# Ruby - Convert XML to JSON without using Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, data-structures

I recently worked on a coding exercise that involved converting XML to JSON. The sane way to do this could be to use the JSON and ActiveSupport gems [as described here.](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/convert-xml-json-using-ruby)
That's what I'd do in production, but it doesn't make me a better coder. So, I've put together my own script, and it works, but frankly I think it's hideous. My question is, how could it be better? What types of techniques and methodologies could I use to make this script simpler, more readable, and more professional?

For reference, we start with the following *input.html* (clean - no edge cases):

```
 <html>
     <body>
          <ul>
               <li>Item One</li>
               <li>Item Two</li>
               <li>
                    <ul>
                         <li>A</li>
                         <li>B</li>
                    </ul>     
               </li>
          </ul>
     </body>
</html>
```

And the JSON output looks like so:

```
{ "html": { "body": { "ul": { "li": ["Item One", "Item Two", { "ul": { "li": ["A", "B"] }  } ]  }  }  }
```

And here's the script - *xml_to_json.rb*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def ucode_strip(obj)
    #remove weird whitespace
    return obj.gsub(/\A[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+\z/, '')
end

def element?(obj)
    #returns true if text is an xml element --e.g. "<html>"
    if ucode_strip(obj) =~ /\A<.*?>/
        true
    end
end

def element(obj)
    #returns html element name --e.g. "<html>" => html, "html" => nil
    stripped = ucode_strip(obj)
    parts = stripped.split(/>/)
    return parts[0].sub(/</, '')
end

def value?(obj)
    #does the line contain information inside of tags <tag>value</tag>
    parts = obj.split(/>/)
    unless !parts[1]
        true
    end
end

def value(obj)
    #returns the value of an xml element --e.g. "<li>item</li>" => "item"
    parts = obj.split(/\</)
    parts[0]
end

def convert_file(file)

    text = File.read(file.to_s)

    lines = text.split(/\n/)

    last_tag = nil
    same_tags = nil
    multiple_values = []

    json = "{ "

    lines.each do |line|
        clean = ucode_strip(line)
        if line =~ /<.*?>/
            unless clean =~ /\A<\// #<opening tag>
                line_elements = clean.split(/>/)

                tag = "\"" + element(line) + "\"" + ':'

                if line_elements[1]
                    #there's more data in this line, not just a tag
                    unless same_tags == true
                        same_tags = true
                        json += tag + " ["
                        last_tag = element(line)
                    else
                        json += ", "
                    end

                    json += "\"" + value(line_elements[1]) + "\""
                else
                    #this line only contains an opening tag
                    same_tags = false #stop building list
                    unless element(line) == last_tag #the previous line started with the same tag
                        json += tag += " { "
                    else
                        json += ", { "
                    end
                    last_tag = tag
                end
            else #</closing tag>
                if same_tags == true
                    #we have a closing tag while building a list
                    same_tags = false #stop building list
                    json += "] } " #first close list, then bracket
                else
                    if clean =~ /#{last_tag}/
                        json += " } ] " #there's an open list we have to 
                    else
                        json += " } " #no open list, just close bracket
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

return json

end

input =  ARGV.first
puts convert_file(input)
```

As I said, this works, but I know it could be better. I realize that there's little-to-no edge case handling, but I'm much more concerned with the way I'm handling the data as a whole. Someone suggested using a ruby list as a stack to store the nested JSON, but I haven't quite figured that out yet. Any help would be much appreciated - if you've gotten this far, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The convert_file method is too complex, it mix the logic of parser and builder together which make it difficult to read, reuse and extend, what i can suggest is to separate this logic out.

The code used to parse the xml file is call a parser, there are three kind of parsers as far as i know , tha SAX, DOM, StAX you can find some reference through google and see how this can be implemented.

The code used to generate json code is call a builder, it is a design pattern, you can find more info through google also.

The stack is a data structure which you may used when implementing the parser and builder.